# Need to optimize a nested select statement

Tags: sql, mysql

I've got the following SQL:

```
SELECT customfieldvalue.ISSUE
FROM   customfieldvalue
WHERE  customfieldvalue.STRINGVALUE 
IN (SELECT customfieldvalue.STRINGVALUE
    FROM   customfieldvalue
    WHERE  customfieldvalue.CUSTOMFIELD = "10670"
    GROUP  BY customfieldvalue.STRINGVALUE
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

The inner nested select returns 3265 rows in 1.5secs on MySQL 5.0.77 when run on its own.
The customfieldvalue table contains 2286831 rows.

I want to return all values of the ISSUE column where the STRINGISSUE column value is not exclusive to that row and the CUSTOMFIELD column contains "10670".

When I try and run the query above, MySQL seems to be stuck. I've left it run for up to a minute, but I'm pretty sure the problem is my query.

Comment: instead of using count(*) use count(1)

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

```
    SELECT cfv1.ISSUE
    COUNT(cfv2.STRINGVALUE) as indicator

    FROM   customfieldvalue cfv1

    INNER JOIN customfieldvalue cfv2
    ON cfv1.STRINGVALUE = cfv2.STRINGVALUE AND cfv2.CUSTOMFIELD = "10670"

    GROUP BY cfv1.ISSUE
    HAVING indicator > 1
```

This probably doesn't work on copy&paste as I haven't verified it, but in MySQL JOINs are **often** much much faster than subqueries, even orders of magnitude.

Comment: I agree that a join should be faster here.

Comment: Post processing to remove duplicates based on JOINs is going to impact your perceived speed boost.  Depends on the number of rows involved, but the larger the dataset, the more likely the approach won't scale.  Use the tool that's right for the job, by checking the EXPLAIN plan & comparing--not based on myths like "JOINs are always faster", and "subqueries are bad".

Comment: @OMG: I added the word "often" to make you feel better. Anyway, what to compare if you have nothing to compare with..